# On Egorove's Theorem

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

In the book [Measure and Intrgral - Wheeden, Zygmund](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=YDkDmQ_hdmcC&pg=PA57&lpg=PA57&dq=egorov%27s+theorem+wheeden+zygmund&source=bl&ots=MfWO9sPROq&sig=eNVizyb11YYpBZJ1tddQTSnL5GQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Hd1JVNeqHIv38QWvqYCQAw&ved=0CDcQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=egorov%27s%20theorem%20wheeden%20zygmund&f=false) (p.57), I saw the Egorove's theorem and its proof. I puzzled with the statements of the Egorove's theorem, and a Lemma needed in the proof of Theorem, as the authors described. They proceed as follows:

(4.17) **Egorove's Theorem:** Suppose $\{f_k\}$ is a sequence of measurable functions which converges a.e. on a set $E$ to a finite limit $f$. Then given $\epsilon>0$, there exists a closed subset $F$ of $E$ such that $|E-F|<\epsilon$ and $\{f_k\}$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $F$.

Before proving this theorem, the authors prove following lemma.

(4.18) **Lemma:** With the same hypothesis as in Egorove's theorem, given $\epsilon,\eta>0$, there exists a closed subset $F$ of $E$ and an integer $K$ such that $|E-F|<\eta$ and 
$|f_k(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ for $x\in F$ and $k>K$.

Considering the statements of Lemma 4.18 and Theorem 4.17, I arrived at following question which I am unable to solve.

**Question:** Is it not true that statement of the Lemma exactly says that $\{f_k\}$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $E-F$? If yes, then why does the authors try to prove Egorove's theorem after proving the Lemma? If not, what is the difference between statements of Lemma and Theorem?

Comment: I will not worry about proofs of the above results, but worrying about their statements only.

Comment: what do you mean by that @Groups ???

Comment: I am not understanding the difference between the statements of Lemma 4.18 and Theorem 4.17. I will not look at proof, until I get clarified with the statements of Lemma and Theorem.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that in the Lemma, you have two "precisions" $\epsilon, \eta$. The first determines the "size" of the set $F$, i.e.  $|E-F|<\epsilon$ and the second determines the closeness of $f_k$ to $f$, i.e. $|f_k -f|<\eta$ on $F$ for $K$ large.

Note that the set $F$ is **allowed to depend on the closeness $\eta$**!

In the statement of the theorem, we **fix** one set $F$, depending only on $\epsilon$. This set will then work for **every precision $\eta$**, because the statement of the theorem says that $f_k \to f$ uniformly on $F$.

Short summary: The Lemma allows the set $F$ to change with the "closeness" of $f_k$ to $f$, whereas the theorem yields one fixed set $F$, which allows arbitrary closeness (uniform convergence).

Comment: OK! I am getting partly clarified with your answer. Can you (or anybody other also) give me an example where $F$ depends on $\epsilon$ also?